# Count number of open cases per month

Tags: python, pyspark

I am currently struggling with one issue about **counting the number of open tasks** at month end with pyspark. I have a dataframe with two timestamps (one for the beginning of the issue, one for the end of the issue). I would like to count the number of open issues at month end.

My dataframe df1 is a merging of two timestamps table (timestamp of the beginning and the end of the task). Let's say it looks like below:

```
TaskNumber  Start Date   StartTimestamp    EndDate     EndTimestamp  EndOfTheMonth        
1           2/15/2019    Start             4/18/2019   End           2/28/2019                            
2           2/16/2019    Start             2/23/2019   End           2/28/2019                             
3           2/17/2019    Start             3/4/2019    End           2/28/2019                             
4           3/1/2019     Start             Null        Null          3/31/2019                            

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, sum as _sum
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    df2 = df1.withColumn("EndOfTheMonth", last_day("Start Date"))

    df3 = (df2.withColumn("OpenTaskAtMonthEnd", when((col("Start Date") <= col("EndOfTheMonth")) & ((col("End Date") >= col("EndOfTheMonth")) | 
(col("EndTask").isNull())),1).otherwise(0))

             .withColumn("TaskStillOpened", when((col("EndTimestamp").isNull()),1).otherwise(0))
             .withColumn("DateofToday", F.current_date())
          )

    df4 = df3.filter(col("OpenTaskAtMonthEnd") == 1)
             .withColumn("Pending Days", when(col("TaskStillOpened") == 1, F.datediff(F.to_date(df3.DateofToday), F.to_date(df3.Start Date))).otherwise(F.datediff(F.to_date(df3.End Date), F.to_date(df3.Start Date))))


    dfOpen = (df4.groupBy("EndOfTheMonth")
             .agg(_sum(col("OpenTaskAtMonthEnd").alias("NrTotalOpenTasksAtMonthEnd"), _sum(col(TasksStillOpened)).alias("TotalWorkinProgress"))
             )


TaskNumber        Start Date    End Date     EndOfTheMonth    OpenTaskatMonthEnd    TaskStillOpen
1                 2/15/2019     4/18/2019    2/28/2019        1                     0
2                 2/16/2019     2/23/2019    2/28/2019        0                     0
3                 2/17/2019     3/4/2019     2/28/2019        1                     0
4                 3/1/2019      Null         3/31/2019        1                     1
```

I manage to count those open tasks for the month n when they have started in this particular month n. But when, a task has begun in the month n-1 and ended only in the month n+1, I cannot find it with my actual code in the open tasks for the month n.

The expected output is indeed to get the number of open tasks for each month and ideally also for each week.

Thanks a lot for your support ;)

Comment: Please share code snippet of what you have tried.

Comment: Could you also please explain what kind of output you expect? A dataframe which contains the open tasks for each month and year?

Comment: I have actualized the previous post. I hope it is a bit clearer. Thanks